# Large consumption of RAM when executing python code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory, hdf5, ram

I have the following code:

```
with open('vector.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.close()

vector = pd.HDFStore('vector.h5', mode='r+')


with open('compare.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.close()

compare = pd.HDFStore('compare.h5', mode='r+')
```

```
for idx, img in enumerate(IMAGE_TITLE):
    
    embedding_main = get_insightface_embedding(PATH_DIR + img) #512 numbers type float
    analyze = get_deepface_analyze(PATH_DIR + img) #string length 15
    embedding_second = get_face_recognition_embedding(PATH_DIR + img) #128 numbers type float

    vector[img] = pd.Series(np.concatenate([embedding_main['embedding'], 
                                            embedding_second,
                                            embedding_main['pose'],
                                            np.array([embedding_main['gender'], \ embedding_main['age'], analyze['dominant_race']])], axis=0))
    imgs_posted = vector.keys()
    
    array = []
    
    for img_vector in imgs_posted:

        metrics_vector1 = compare_vector_cosine(vector[img][:512], vector[img_vector][:512])
        
        array.append(metrics_vector1)
     
    compare[img] = pd.Series(data=np.array(array), index=imgs_posted)
```

Why does it use a lot of RAM ? How can its use be reduced ?

I need to optimally compare some images, in the first version I used a large matrix, but the problem is that it does not fit in memory. Then I decided to save the parts on the hard disk using hdf5 (I'm not familiar with it), but my code still does not work optimally, spending 9 GB of RAM when comparing 2000 images. Tell me, what could be the problem? What can I do wrong? And is it possible to make the code even more optimal?

Comment: I suspect `HDFStore()` loads the entire file as a dataframe in memory. How large is it?

Comment: I keep a series in each key that increases by one to 2000. Then the total number of elements in each key from 1 to 2000 is 2001000, these are float numbers.

Comment: Maybe it's because I keep vector and compare in RAM ?

Comment: But if we calculate the amount of memory occupied when fully reading vector and compare, it will be no more than 0.1 GB. The question is relevant, what is the RAM used for?

Comment: When you mean by "9 GB of RAM"? Process memory or file size on disk? If process memory, how are you measuring it? I ask because I created a simple example to replicate your process and data structures. When it runs, the memory footprint (from Windows Task Manager) is never more than 500 MiB and the vector.h5 file is 40 MiB. However,  the compare.h5 file is **9.7 Gib**. My conclusion: the process above doesn't consume a lot of memory, but it's possible 1 of the supporting functions does (especially `compare_vector_cosine()` ). Or, maybe you are referring to the size of compare.h5?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to diagnose you problem without understanding the data structures and the associated functions. Can you create a simple example that mimics the behavior? (See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))  That said, I will offer some comments on your code in hopes it helps you isolate the problem.

First, these 4 lines of code at the top do nothing. Delete them. They simply open and close the 2 files. Also, you don't need (and shouldn't use) `f.close()` with Python's file context manager. The file is closed automatically when you exit the `with/as:` block.

```
with open('vector.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.close()

with open('compare.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.close()
```

Now on to the rest of the code. First, re-write your `HDFStore()` calls to use the context manager like this:

```
with pd.HDFStore('vector.h5', mode='r+') as vector, \
     pd.HDFStore('compare.h5', mode='r+') as compare:
```

The following lines of code should all be indented to be part of the `with/as:` block above. I assume IMAGE_TITLE is an iterable (List or similar).

```
for idx, img in enumerate(IMAGE_TITLE):
    
    embedding_main = get_insightface_embedding(PATH_DIR + img) #512 numbers type float
    analyze = get_deepface_analyze(PATH_DIR + img) #string length 15
    embedding_second = get_face_recognition_embedding(PATH_DIR + img) #128 numbers type float
```

The line of code below creates a Pandas dataframe and adds to the `vector` HDFStore with `key name=img`. It looks like `embedding_main` is a dictionary with at least 3 keys: 'embedding', 'pose', and 'gender'. Also, `analyze` appears to be a dictionary too (with key='dominant_race'). This is different than comments above, so more details are required.

```
vector[img] = pd.Series(np.concatenate([embedding_main['embedding'], 
                                        embedding_second,
                                        embedding_main['pose'],
                                        np.array([embedding_main['gender'],  
                                                  embedding_main['age'], 
                                                  analyze['dominant_race']]) ], 
                                                  axis=0) )
```

I think your problem occurs in the following lines. Remember they are inside the for loop above! The following line gets all of names of all keys (dataframes) added to the HDFStore. So, the first time, it will get 1 key, then 2 keys, then 3 keys and so on until 2000 on the last loop above.

```
imgs_posted = vector.keys()
```

Next in the code that below, you loop on the keys, extracting vectors and adding them to `array'. So on the first outer loop it will have 1 vector, then 2, then 3 and so on until there are 2000 vectors in the last outer loop. I don't think that is what you intended.

```
array = []   
for img_vector in imgs_posted:
    metrics_vector1 = compare_vector_cosine(vector[img][:512], vector[img_vector][:512])       
    array.append(metrics_vector1)
```

Finally, you create a Pandas series with a np.array created from the list of vectored stored in `array` extracted above and add to the `compare` HDFStore with `key name=img`. There will be A LOT of vectors in `array`.

```
compare[img] = pd.Series(data=np.array(array), index=imgs_posted)
```